# How to pause in an array after each reaching some count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of symbols in javascript  .

For each element of an Array , i am sending it to a server , and i am doing this operation continously for every 10
seconds using setTimeout .

My requirement is that , once i process the half of the symbols in the array , i want to give a pause the operation for 3 seconds .

(The size of the array is fixed that is 100 , so i can directly use the condition if it reached 50 )

I have tried this with a sample program ,

I observed that when the page is loaded for the first time , affter reaching 2 symbols , its ausing for 2 seconds .
and from the next iteartion its not pauisng .

Could anybody please help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var symbols = ["One","Two","Three","FOur"];
var i = 0;

function doPoll() {
$.each( symbols, function( index, value ){
loadXMLDoc(value);
});
setTimeout(doPoll, 10000);

}


$(document).ready(function () {

doPoll();
});


function loadXMLDoc(value)
{
    i++;
    alert(value);
    if(i==2)
    sleep(1000);


}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
var start = new Date().getTime();
for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
break;
}
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know that `sleep` freezes the whole UI thread of the browser?

Comment: Although, in your case you can simply iterate over the first of the array (with a normal for loop), use `setTimeout` and then iterate over the second half of the array. You don't have to process each item individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can simply iterate over the first half of the array (with a normal `for` loop), use `setTimeout` and then iterate over the second half of the array:

```
function doPoll() {
   var middle = Math.round(symbols.length / 2);
   for (var i = 0, l = middle; i < l; i++) {
       loadXMLDoc(symbols[i]);
   }
   setTimeout(function() {
       for (var i = middle, l = symbols.length; i < l; i++) {
         loadXMLDoc(symbols[i]);
       }
       setTimeout(doPoll, 10000);
   }, 2000);
}
```

See also: [Best way to insert a 'pause' in a .each enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6739557/218196)

Comment: Works perfectly , thanks once again , initially i thought of using sleep , which i was seeing some browser issues .